# merge/minimize multiple javascript document.body.innerHTML.replace

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml

I have this javascript code which is basically 3 of the (near) same but replacements are different:

```
var d = document;
d.body.innerHTML = d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/g,'fooo');
d.body.innerHTML = d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foobar/g,'fooobaaar');
d.body.innerHTML = d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foobarlicious"/g,'');
```

is it possible to minimize it someway?

I tried this (knowing it wouldn't work):

```
d.body.innerHTML = d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/g,'fooo'),
                   d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foobar/g,'fooobaaar'),
                   d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foobarlicious"/g,'');
```

and of course it didn't.....

I also tried to var `document.body.innerHTML` as

```
var dbi = document.body.innerHTML;
```

and this also didn't work hense just having `var d = document;` is there a reason why this dosen't work?

Comment: You can simply chain the `.replace()` calls, but it's worth pointing out that this isn't a good way to do a replace on a document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the `.replace()` methods:

```
d.body.innerHTML = d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/g,'fooo').replace(/foobar/g,'fooobaaar').replace(/foobarlicious"/g,'');
```

...but you can keep some white-space to make it readable:

```
d.body.innerHTML = d.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/g,'fooo')
                                   .replace(/foobar/g,'fooobaaar')
                                   .replace(/foobarlicious"/g,'');
```

Regarding the `dbi` variable that you asked about:

> *I also tried to var document.body.innerHTML as*
>
> ```
> var dbi = document.body.innerHTML;
> ```
>
> *and this also didn't work hense just having `var d = document;` is there a reason why this dosen't work?*

Your `dbi` variable would be a string set to the initial value of the body's html, but it doesn't retain a live link to the document body. You can do replacements or other manipulation on that variable, but to see the changes in your document you'd have to assign it back:

```
document.body.innerHTML = dbi;
```

Your `d = document` thing worked because `d` is a live reference to the document itself.

Answer (score 1):

Either chain them, as mentioned above, or store the innerHTML as a variable and set the innerHTML after you edit the variable as much as needed.

```js
var iH = document.body.innerHTML;
iH = iH.replace(/foo/g,'fooo');
iH = iH.replace(/foobar/g,'fooobaaar');
iH = iH.replace(/foobarlicious"/g,'');
document.body.innerHTML = iH;
```

As already mentioned, though, editing the innerHTML of the body is **not** a good idea.

Comment: `editing the innerHTML of the body is not a good idea` ...It is for a GreaseMonkey userscript

Comment: No it's not. It can always be done a better way, without de-serializing and re-serializing the DOM. I've been writing for Greasemonkey since 2007, so trust me, there are better ways.

Comment: So please give example of better solution I'm fairly new to JavaScript and so all help is appreciated.

Comment: Well what do you want to do?